# How to change the color of vector layer of QGIS in api?

Tags: qgis, vector, layers, api, color

I'm using QGIS-2.4.0 api to develop app in C++. When I add a vector layer to the app, the vector map's color would be random. I used QgsFeatureRendererV2 to get the geometry type of the layer, my provider name is ogr. 
My question is: how to set a solid color to the layer?

Answer (score 4):

http://qgis.org/api/2.2/classQgsSymbolV2.html#aa2c7db61d4234bddf3aa62f294ad6818

```
void QgsSymbolV2::setColor(const QColor & color)
```

with python:

```
myColour = QtGui.QColor('#ffee00')
mySymbol1 = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(myVectorLayer.geometryType())
mySymbol1.setColor(myColour)
```